# How to filter specific image coordinates from an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, astronomy

I am reading an image, getting objects that have a certain brightness value, and then plotting the X and Y coords to the image.

[image: Problem/outliers]

But, there is a *huge* group of outliers, which are all located in a rectangular part of the image, Its X and Y coords are 1110-1977 (width) and 1069-1905 (height). From here, I'm looping through this little square portion of the image, and from my pre-created x and y arrays any values that have the same coords as shown there are removed.

However, this removes a lot more coords, which, for example, have X in the range 1110-1977. So the end result is a cross pattern filtering when I only want the square in the center to be filtered. How would I do this?

[image]

Code

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
imag = Image.open("Centaurus_A-DeNoiseAI-denoise.jpg")
imag = imag.convert ('RGB')
x=[]
y=[]
imag2=Image.open("Cen_A_cropped.jpg")
imag2=imag2.convert('RGB')
r=[]
g=[]
b=[]
width2, height2=imag2.size
for count2 in range(width2):
    for i2 in range(height2):
        X,Y=count2,i2
        (R,G,B)=imag2.getpixel((X,Y))
        r.append(R)
        g.append(G)
        b.append(B)
average_r=sum(r)/len(r)
average_g=sum(g)/len(g)
average_b=sum(b)/len(b)
brightness_average=sqrt(0.299*(average_r**2) + 0.587*(average_g**2) + 0.114*(average_b**2))
print("Avg. brightness "+str(brightness_average))
def calculate_brightness(galaxy,ref_clus,clus_mag):
    delta_b=(galaxy/ref_clus)
    bright=delta_b**2
    mag=np.log(bright)/np.log(2.512)
    return mag+clus_mag
count=0
X,Y = 1556,1568
(R,G,B) = imag.getpixel((X,Y))
width, height=imag.size
brightness = sqrt(0.299*(R**2) + 0.587*(G**2) + 0.114*(B**2))
print("Magnitude: "+str((calculate_brightness(13050, 15.79,3.7))))
reference=brightness_average/(calculate_brightness(13050, 15.79,3.7)/6.84)
print("Reference: "+str(reference))
for count in range(width):
    for i in range(height):
        X,Y = count,i
        (R,G,B) = imag.getpixel((X,Y))
        brightness = sqrt(0.299*(R**2) + 0.587*(G**2) + 0.114*(B**2))
        if(reference<=brightness<=reference+3):
            x.append(X)
            y.append(Y)

#post processing----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for x2 in range(1110, 1977):
    for y2 in range(1069, 1905):
        X,Y=x2,y2
        if(X in x and Y in y):
            x.remove(X)
            y.remove(Y)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with imag as im:
    delta = 19
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        draw.rectangle([x[i-delta],y[i-delta],x[i-delta],y[i-delta]], fill=(0,255,0))

    im.save("your_image.png")
```

[Centaurus_A-DeNoiseAI-denoise.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lfz5phaT-X4UBrj0BZhUmL56lubU86lC/view?usp=sharing)

[Cen_A_cropped.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HK6m-wC0aa1FunKtocR-LxVQefoMDQ5F/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can't understand your criteria based on what you've provided here.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how in the second image there is more removed than you want, and I can't see a cross. (edit: okay, in the full-res image we can see that the green dots are cut away in a shape that looks like a cross)

Comment: Sorry, I have applied the full code, see if you get what is going on from this

Comment: No problem I will have to drive it, bear with me

Comment: This is "Cen_A_cropped" https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HK6m-wC0aa1FunKtocR-LxVQefoMDQ5F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the other: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lfz5phaT-X4UBrj0BZhUmL56lubU86lC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've made some major edits to your question which I think make your problem clearer. Feel free to rollback the changes, or correct any mistakes I may have made.

Comment: Thank you, my weak point is writing, I appreciate you taking the time to do this for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post-processing logic is flawed. You remove a bunch of X values in the range 1110-1977, without checking whether its corresponding Y value is also in the range of the box. Remove this code section instead and add that logic the first time you loop to gather your x and y coords.

```
for count in range(width):
    for i in range(height):
        X,Y = count,i
        if 1110 <= X < 1977 and 1069 <= Y < 1905:    # add these
            continue                                 # two lines
        (R,G,B) = imag.getpixel((X,Y))
```

However, there is a better way of doing the exact same thing by using numpy arrays. Instead of writing explicit loops, you can vectorise a lot of your computations.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image = Image.open('Centaurus_A-DeNoiseAI-denoise.jpg').convert('RGB')
img1 = np.array(image)
img2 = np.array(Image.open('Cen_A_cropped.jpg').convert('RGB'))

coeffs = np.array([.299, .587, .114])
average = img2.mean(axis=(0, 1))
brightness_average = np.sqrt(np.sum(average**2 * coeffs))
reference = brightness_average / (calculate_brightness(13050, 15.79,3.7) / 6.84)
print(f'Avg. brightness: {brightness_average}')
print(f'Reference: {reference}')

brightness = np.sqrt(np.sum(img1.astype(int)**2 * coeffs, axis=-1))
accepted_brightness = (brightness >= reference) * (brightness <= reference + 3)
pixels_used = np.ones((img1.shape[:2]), dtype=bool)
pixels_used[1069:1905,1110:1977] = False
rows, cols = np.where(accepted_brightness * pixels_used)

with image as im:
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.point(list(zip(cols, rows)), fill=(0, 255, 0))
    image.save('out.png')
```

The main trick used here is in the line

```
rows, cols = np.where(accepted_brightness * pixels_used)
```

`accepted_brightess` is a 2d array of each pixel with a boolean value whether its brightness is within your preferred range. `pixels_used` is another 2d boolean array, where every pixel is `True`, except from the pixels in the box near the centre you want to ignore. The combination of those two gives you the pixel coordinates that have the correct brightness and are not in the square in the centre.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not familiar with the NumPy library, and its possibilities so I did not use it, good to know my project can be done 100x faster!

Comment: I just sort of created logic and used good old python to implement it, numpy makes it so much FASTER!

Comment: @AstronomyComputing Numpy can be quite powerful when used properly indeed.

Comment: Well, this changes how I write every array-related code now! It's time to learn how to use Numpy!

Comment: @AstronomyComputing [This](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html) should cover the basics and the majority of the functionality one would use most frequently.